# Batch find and replace string adds blank line

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I got this code (in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879928/batch-check-and-replace-string-then-wait-for-a-process)) that finds and replaces string but it adds a blank new line at the end of the output file and makes it not usable.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "Russian=g_language = Russian"
set "English=g_language = English"

set "textfile=user.cfg"
set "newfile=user.bak"

Call :SwapLang Russian

:search
Color 9B
@echo off&prompt :&mode con cols=60 lines=16


echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                      PLEASE RUN NOTEPAD
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.

:search
TIMEOUT /T 2
TASKLIST|FIND "notepad.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (GOTO found) ELSE (GOTO search)

:found

Call :SwapLang English

Goto :Eof

:SwapLang %1 byRef
( for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
  set "line=%%i"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  If /I "!line:~0,12!" Equ "g_language =" (
    echo(!%1!
  ) Else (
    echo(!line!
  )
  endlocal
)) > "%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
Goto :Eof
```

**INPUT FILE:** It has 6 line with no blank line.

```
sys_usefrontline = 1
net_frontline_address = s1.gmru.net
net_frontline_port = 5050
g_language = Russian
cl_promoPageWidth = 820
cl_promoPageHeight = 726
```

**OUTPUT1 FILE:** It has 7 lines, last line is blank (can't be shown here).

```
sys_usefrontline = 1
net_frontline_address = s1.gmru.net
net_frontline_port = 5050
g_language = Russian
cl_promoPageWidth = 820
cl_promoPageHeight = 726
```

**OUTPUT2 FILE:** It has 7 lines, last line is blank(can't be shown here).

```
sys_usefrontline = 1
net_frontline_address = s1.gmru.net
net_frontline_port = 5050
g_language = English
cl_promoPageWidth = 820
cl_promoPageHeight = 726
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: There is nothing in the code to produce an additional line. Do you mean "The last line in my Input File has no termination (`CRLF`)"? Does the `CRLF` really make the file unusable?

Comment: I dont know realy.

Comment: @Stephan Echo always terminates a line with a cr/lf. The very last line of the file didn't and shouldn't have a cr/lf. I went to PowerShell but it's Set-Content did the same. Only way around I found was dot net's `[IO.File]::WriteAllText()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch isn't ideal for editing files. This batch uses PowerShell to do the editing with a Regular Expression:

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\08\25\SO_45879928.cmd
@echo off &setlocal

set "textfile=user.cfg"

Call :SwapLang Russian

:search
Color 9B
@echo off&prompt :&mode con cols=60 lines=16
echo.
echo.
echo                      PLEASE RUN NOTEPAD
echo.
echo.
:search
TIMEOUT /T 2
TASKLIST|FIND "notepad.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (GOTO found) ELSE (GOTO search)

:found

Call :SwapLang English

Goto :Eof

:SwapLang %1
Powershell -NoP -C "$txt=(gc %textfile% -raw) -replace '(?<=g_language = )(English|Russian)','%1';[IO.File]::WriteAllText('%textfile%', $txt)"

Goto :Eof
```

Comment: Result is same as for batch from above. I think I will give up from this approach and try copy>rename file approach.

Comment: Looks like `sc` or `Set-Content` also puts a terminating cd/lf to the end of the file [refernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751320/powershell-replace-content-in-file-adds-redundent-carriage-return) Workaround from the answer in the reference incorporated in my answer here. Should work now.

Comment: @ LotPings I have to thank you for your time and effort that you invested in answering my questions!

Comment: The most welcome thank is: If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Now it deletes file content in first pass @ `Call :SwapLang Russian`

Comment: I checked with the very last version and found no problem?  Do the other values in the file change regularly? What about a simple `copy /y Russian.cfg user.cfg` or `copy /y English.cfg user.cfg`?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved your **original question**: [Batch check and replace string then wait for a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879928/batch-check-and-replace-string-then-wait-for-a-process) by just 2 command lines using `msr.exe` as following: (full message is there, with *a colorful screenshot*)

`msr -p user.cfg -it "(g_language\s*=\s*)\w*" -o "${1}Russian" -R`

`msr -p user.cfg -it "(g_language\s*=\s*)\w*" -o "${1}English" -R`

**Additonaly, for your questions here**, also 1 command to remove tail new lines:

`msr -p your-files-dirs -S -t "[\r\n]+$" -o "" -R`

Or remove tail white-spaces and new lines:

`msr -p your-files-dirs -S -t "\s+$" -o "" -R`

According to stackoverflow rules, say again here: `msr.exe`/`msr.gcc*`/`msr.cygwin` etc is in **my open project** https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory, as a general tool to **M**atch/**S**earch/**R**eplace files/pipe lines/blocks.